# Multi-tenant API application never shows up in other directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a multi-tenant Web API application(created through Ibiza AAD UX) that never shows up in other AAD tenants for granting permissions. I made sure to mark "Multi-tenanted = Yes" during property definition of the AAD application.

Any help to troubleshoot this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rao

Answer (score 1):

When a new user in another tenant signs into the multi-tenant app and consents, a service principal (not an app object) is provisioned into the tenant.  The Azure Portal (as you said Ibiza UX) *App Registrations* blade represents application objects.

You can checkout the Service Principals in a tenant using a couple of techniques, but the easiest is through the *Enterprise Apps* blade in the Azure Portal or using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and running a query on /servicePrincipals.

Comment: I have web app in tenant1 and multi-tenant api app in tenant2; trying to configure web app's access to api app using the "Required Permissions" blade. The api app doesn't show in the "Select an API" blade.

Comment: Hey @user883114 that seems like a new question :). Following StackOverflow decorum, can you post it and I'll go answer it!

Comment: sorry a newbie:(